# in C# and sqlite datetime values are wrongly inserted or wrongly queried

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, insert

I had problem in inserting datetime values to sqlite database in C#. Later i found a way to do it. Now i can insert DateTime values by formatting them like this

```
data.Add("sayacTarihZamani", string.Format("{0:u}", MydateTimeData));
```

I can see that data is inserted to the database table correctly using a sqlite admin tool. 
When i query this data the values which come are wrong.  The values are 3 hours later then its normal value.

For example in admin tool i see `30.03.2011 16:00:00` value but in C# grid the value is `30.03.2011 19:00:00` ..

There is one exception to this. I manually entered a row using the admin tool. It's date value is 
`30.03.2011 11:30:00` in datagrid it is still `30.03.2011 11:30:00` (true)

How can i correctly insert and query the datetime data using sqlite and C#.

Thank you for your time,
Ferda

Comment: have you normalized the timezones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.Add("sayacTarihZamani", string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", mydatetime));

worked all right.

Thank you for your help
Ferda

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `u` specifier, your DateTime is automatically converted to universal time.  [From the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#UniversalFull) (emphasis mine):

> The "U" standard format specifier represents a custom date and time
>   format string that is defined by a specified culture's
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.FullDateTimePattern property. The pattern is the
>   same as the "F" pattern. However, **the DateTime value is automatically
>   converted to UTC before it is formatted**.

Try using the `F` pattern instead if you want to store the local time.

Comment: Hi when i use F pattern it inserts date values wrong. like this 30.12.1899 00:20:11  instead of 30.03.2011 16:00:00  . It gives the same value to different hhours also for example for 30.03.2011 15:00:00  the value is also 30.12.1899 00:20:11 (same and wrong)